# favicon to base64 fails on this site

Tags: html, favicon

I have written a function that returns the favicon by splitting the document's `<head>` `<link>` tags

- `rel="icon"`
- `rel="shortcut icon"`

```
function geticon(site,cb){
    if(site.indexOf('http')==-1){site='http://'+site;}
    $.get("https://mysite.me/middleman.php",{"site":site})
    .always(function(d){
        if(!d){cb('https://mysite.me/R/link.png',false);}
        else{
            d=d.split('<link ');
            var ico='https://mysite.me/R/link.png';
            for(var i=0;i<d.length;i+=1){
                d[i]=d[i].split('>')[0];
                if(d[i].indexOf('rel="icon"')!==-1||d[i].indexOf('rel="shortcut icon"')!==-1){
                    ico=(d[i].split('href="')[1]).split('"')[0];
                    break;
                    }}
            site=(site.split('//')[1]).split('/')[0];
            if(ico.indexOf(site)==-1&&ico.indexOf('http')!=0&&ico.indexOf('//')!=0){
                if(ico[0]=='/'){ico=site+ico;}
                else{ico=site+'/'+ico;}
                }
            if(ico.indexOf('http')==-1){
                if(ico.indexOf('//')==0){ico='http:'+ico;}
                else{ico='http://'+ico;}
                }
            if(!ico){cb('https://mysite.me/R/link.png',false);}
            else{
                getimg(ico,function(b,bool){cb(b,bool);});//returns base64 string
                }}});}
```

but it fails to work with this url:

http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2012/09/07/uspto-issues-worlds-first-invisibility-cloak-patent/id=27841/

I have looked at the source code for the url but cannot identify the favicon in the code, yet the browser tab does have an image of a dog with a magnifying glass!

what am I missing? how many ways of declaring a favicon are there?

Comment: If the website doesn’t specify any of those, browsers also request `/favicon.ico`. Consider doing this in PHP with proper HTML parsing, too.

Comment: that is probably it!!

If so i will update the code in an answer! (New code will try to get that ico first before it digs through the tags)

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The favicon is located at http://www.ipwatchdog.com/favicon.ico following method 2 in the W3C's [How to Add a Favicon to your Site](https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon) which lists two methods of including a favicon on a website:

1. Referencing it in a link tag.
2. Putting it in a file named "favicon" at the root of the domain.